# How to disable an armature modifier in a single animation for character's clothes in order to animate them separately?

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature

I want to temporarily animate clothes of my character, for example taking off shoes or watch. I don't understand how to manipulate objects armature modifiers while animating them (clothes) in a separate way. I need some solution to detach an object from character's armature inside an animation.

Comment: Child of constraint? Influence value?

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I'll try that out. I'm not really experienced with that, so naming the directions is really helpful for me.

Comment: the shoe can be part of the body most of the time, but when the character needs to tak off his shoes, make it a different object and use the Dynamic Parent addon so that it can be parented to the foot bone, then to the hand bone, then released, etc...

Comment: @moonboots oh, thank you, I think that's gonna work for me nicely